# Buttons or TouchableOpacity are not clickable inside a header with ImageBackground in the android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my application there is a header with ImageBackground. When I use TouchableOpacity or Button inside it, it is not clickable. I tried wrapping it with a view and tried giving it a zIndex as well. But none working.
The react and react native versions are:

> "react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.2",

Ideally the button should be clickable with ImageBackground. But when I remove the ImageBackground, only then the button is clickable.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Alert, Text } from 'react-native';

const CustomHeader = () => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1 }}
      source={require('../../Assets/Images/app-bg.png')}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 25,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
          marginTop: 10,
        }}
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("You clicked me")}
      >
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

export default CustomHeader;
```

**Edit**
I am calling the header component in the following way:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="SplashScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerMode: 'screen',
          headerTintColor: '#404554',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
          header: (props) => {
            return <CustomHeader {...props} />;
          },
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainDrawer" component={MainDrawerNavigation} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: I just copy your code in my app and the button clickable for me!!!
But you can wrap the TouchableOpacity in a View and try again.

Comment: Exactly when I use this as header component, the problem occurs

Comment: I actually wrapped the code in the View but for the sake of simplicity I pasted it raw here

Comment: Can you show me where you use this component?

Comment: Or Maybe when you use this component as header to screen this problem occured.

Comment: Post has been updated

Comment: I copy your code again and set `MainDrawerNavigation` to this:
`const MainDrawerNavigation = () => {
  return <View style={{flex: 1}} />;
};`
and again the alert is shown! I think your screen style caused this problem!
You may pass the height or flex to screen and disable header.